# When $n\mid\sum_{k=1}^{n}\phi (k)$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, totient-function

Consider this function.

$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\phi (k)$$

where $\phi (k)$ is the Euler's totient function. I'm wondering are there infinitely many $n$ such that $n\mid f(n)$? For $n\leq 4000$ only solutions are $1, 2, 5, 6, 16, 25, 36, 249, 617, 1296$

Comment: The OEIS recognizes your list (under the same definition you give) but suggests that it is "not obviously infinite".  There are a few links (and many more entries) available there:  https://oeis.org/A048290/internal

Comment: Thank you. How did you find this article? I can't use oesis.org's search engine effectively. Did you search the list of numbers? Or the sum function?

Comment: I just cut and pasted your list into their search line.  I was hoping it would be recognized with a different definition...something easier to break down, but no such luck.